# Заполнение excel файла из php

Tags: php, phpexcel

Доброе время суток. Для заполнения шаблона excel из php использую компонент **PhpExcel**. То ли я ничего не понимаю, то ли реально какая то ерунда тварится... Прошу помощи.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `price` WHERE id IN (".$r.")", $dblink);

while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $repair[] = $result1[1];
}
$repair_count = count($repair);

for($i=0, $s=16; $i <= $repair_count; $i++, $s++){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$s, $repair[$i]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$s, $worker);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. получается php думает, что я на 45 строке что то вывожу в браузер, но ведь это не так... Притом если там написать статичную переменную (а не циклом перебирать массив) проблемы не возникает.

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Помогите пожалуйста, очень надо... Второй день уже мучаюсь... Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле вы не на 45 строке что-то выводите.

Это у вас Notice, что на 45 строке кода нет такого элемента в массиве.

Поэтому потом появляется предупреждение, уже о том, что выше был тот самый Notice.

Судя по всему, вам мешает `$i <= $repair_count`. Ведь для одного элемента в массиве эта переменная будет равна 1. А система попытается записать в ячейку снучала `$repair[0]`, а потом `$repair[1]`, которой нет.

Исправьте `<=` на `<`, и всё будет хорошо.